# Angular 2 preferred language?

Tags: angular

With Angular 2 available in more than one dialect, is there one that's considered the default / preferred / recommended?

I've been using Angular 1.1 - 1.4 in my projects, but now that Angular 2 is a whole new ball game, and I'm about to start from scratch. I would like to know whether I should start with a language other than JavaScript this time. Or put it otherwise, whether sticking with the JavaScript version of Angular JS is going to leave me behind in any way.

Comment: @TotaloDotoNeto this is absolutely not what I asked.

Comment: ohh... sorry i have removed my earlier comment, to avoid confusion. Can you please specify what's your question if it not related to Angular 1+ to Angular 2 migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, probably [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Typescript is a superset of Javascript which compiles to plain Javascript, there isn't much to learn.

Angular 2 is built with type languages Typescript and [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/). I'm not sure how much momentum Dart has, but Typescript seems to be here to stay.

Practically speaking, Typescript saves typing and of course allows you to have types. The syntax  hovers around the ES2016/ES2017 specs, so in that respect its simliar to Javascript. Especially with the [new Typescript version supporting async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/11/03/what-about-async-await.aspx) :)

There are differences, and a little bit of learning/tooling, but yeah Typescript.